# Java - Socket needs delay to receive correct data?

Tags: java, arrays, sockets

I am writing a Java program using sockets to receive data from a C program.

The C program mallocs an integer array to fit the number of elements to be put inside. For example: {111,2,2,2,3,3} (111 is just a message header), so the int[] size is 6. (We free the array after sending is completed with a return value of 0 which is success). We print out the contents of the array, everything is displayed as expected: 111,2,2,2,3,3

However, we realize that in Java, we need to add a minor delay before reading from input stream, otherwise we can't get the correct values. E.g. if we don't put a Thread.sleep(2000) before input stream available, the value Java receive is like 111,0,0,0,3,3 (e.g. the value 2 is lost)

1) Does it affect Java if I send int array in C and ask Java to read int by int?

2) Why does the delay make the data accurate? We try playing around with 1000,1500 but only 2000 gives the most stable result

3) If in SomeAction.class, i put busy wait:

```
while (!pcClient.readMessage());
```

or

```
while (!pcClient.readMessage()) {}
```

it only go the while loop once and just break out? Whereas if I do this below , it works as intended:

```
while (!pcClient.readMessage()) {System.out.print("");}
```

Comment: Can you share the C code?

Comment: I'm not good at C, but I thought that `sizeof msg_queue` is the size of the pointer, not the size of int. Isn't it? In this case it might be 8 instead of 4

Comment: @bedrin when i tried to do a printf("%d, %d", count, sizeof msg_queue); just above the malloc, it shows 6, 4

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Does it affect Java if I send int array in C and ask Java to read int by int?

When you ask Java to read it int by int, it basically waits for next 4 bytes available and builds an `int` value out of these 4 bytes

Looks like your Java client starts reading data before your C server starts writing it - that's why a delay of 2 seconds solve your problem

You can simply remove the `if(dataIn.available() > 0) { }` condition - `dataIn.readInt()` will block until the data is available on the wire

Comment: i'm suspicious of this as well that's why we put 111 as a header before we try to process the next 5 integers but unfortunately it didn't work as intended as the middle/ending values gets lost in a random fashion

Comment: we tried removing the dataIn.available() > 0, and the result we got is something like this: Unknown: 6 Unknown: 0 Unknown: 0 Unknown: 0 Unknown: 2 Unknown: 3

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating and sending the wrong length. `msg_queue` is a pointer, and its size is irrelevant to the message length. `sizeof msg_queue` should be `sizeof int` throughout. You're sending too much data, so the receiver is getting out of sync.

Remove the pointless sleep and `available()` test. The subsequent reads will block for exactly the right length of time, unlike your sleep.

You don't need to clear the dynamic message befor freeing it. You don't even need to allocate the message dynamically, as its size is known at compile time.

Comment: Hi I have updated my solution in my main post based on your suggestions, but the problem still persists without a 500ms sleep. Any idea what is happening in Java side or is it the C program still wrong?

Comment: I'm not interested until you get rid of the sleep and the `available()` test as per my answer.